# How do I clean up image uploading by removing the additional upload fields?

Tags: 6, media, files

I am running a Drupal 6 site, and I have a content type in which the user can upload a maximum of 6 images. The problem I am having is that I don't like the fact that Drupal displays all 6 file upload slots. I would prefer that it would just display one upload slot and then display the add additional image button like it does when it is configured to upload unlimited images.

Is it possible to configure Drupal to do this? I have searched high and low, and I can't find anything.

Can anyone point me to a module or to some code to accomplish this?

Comment: Still looking for an answer to the this question. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Although it may not be what you exactly want. I'm not going to write all the code for you, but can push you in the right direction:

1. Make the field accept unlimited values. That will add your "Add another" button, and will only show 1 image upload field initially.
2. Make a small module which implements hook_form_alter and modify the node_form of the content type which has the image. You need to add an extra validation function.
3. Write the validation function to check the number of values supplied in the image field. And set form error if more than 6 images uploaded.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try. It would be nice if this was the default behavour of Drupal.

Comment: I have made it up to step 3 but not sure how to implement this. The "Add Another" button is a javascript function, so how would you go about implementing a check on something on the client side from a module?